# Get current control name from context menu

Tags: powershell, treeview, contextmenu

I am wring a forms script in power shell. In the form, i have few list view controls which will populate dynamically with values. I have created a single context menu with values "Export Data" & "Refresh Data" and attached it to all the list view controls. context menu is showing fine when i right click on any of the list view control. I need to export/refresh the data in that particular list view controls when i click the menu. I have the functions to export the data & refresh the data in the list view controls.

My question is, how can i get the list view name on which i have click? so that i can execute the functions associated with that particular list view.

Here is the code.

```
$ctxMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
$ctxExportDataMenuItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ctxExportDataMenuItem.Text = "Export To CSV"
$ctxRefreshDataMenuItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ctxRefreshDataMenuItem.Text = "Refresh"        
$ctxExportDataMenuItem.Add_Click({Export-ToCsv})
$ctxRefreshDataMenuItem.Add_Click({Refresh-ListView"})
$ctxMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(@($ctxExportDataMenuItem,$ctxRefreshDataMenuItem)) 

$sysSysEvtListView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$sysAppEvtListView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView 

$sysSysEvtListView.ContextMenu = $ctxMenu
$frmMain.Controls.Add($sysSysEvtListView) | Out-Null

$sysAppEvtListView.ContextMenu = $ctxMenu
$frmMain.Controls.Add($sysAppEvtListView) | Out-Null
```

when clicked on any of the list view, i need to capture that controls name into a variable. then in export-tocsv function, i will execute the code depending the control name.

Thanks for helping me in this query. :)

Comment: Would help to see your code and let use know what part you are referring to.

Comment: code has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within the event handler script block you can access $this and $_ which refer to the Sender and EventArgs of the event. In the MenuItem event handler you can get the ListView name like so:

```
$ctxRefreshDataMenuItem.Add_Click({Write-Host $this.Parent.SourceControl.Name})
```